Failing to emulate Pixel 3a using flutter provided emulator on linux
I want to code flutter apps using my Ubuntu Linux laptop, however, i can't seem to make the Pixel 3a API emulator to work.
Whenever I try to run the emulator, I get the following error:
Starting device daemon...
[ERR] The Android emulator exited with code 1 during startup
[ERR] Android emulator stderr:
[ERR] WARNING | Failed to process .ini file /home/yazzine/.android/avd/../avd/Pixel_3a_API_34_extension_level_7_x86_64.avd/quickbootChoice.ini for reading.
[ERR] ERROR   | x86_64 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
[ERR] CPU acceleration status: /dev/kvm is not found: VT disabled in BIOS or KVM kernel module not loaded
[ERR] More info on configuring VM acceleration on Linux:
[ERR] https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#vm-linux
[ERR] General information on acceleration: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.
[ERR] Address these issues and try again.

I think it's a problem related to virtualization not enabled on my laptop, because when i run flutter doctor every box is checked. Here is a view on this command:
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.22.2, on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS 6.5.0-44-generic, locale
    en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.91.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] Network resources

Could anyone help me with this problem? Thank you in advance!
